# Redefine value from enum

Tags: c, types, typedef

I have this code defined in the 3rd party library I'm using:

```
typedef enum {
   STATE_INITIAL  = 0,
   STATE_LOAD     = 1,
   STATE_READ     = 2,
   STATE_FINISH   = 3
} state_t;
```

I would like to re-define the value of STATE_FINISH. However, I don't want to mess with the library, and at the same time I can't do it this way in my code:

```
#undef STATE_FINISH
#define STATE_FINISH 2
```

Is there another way?

Comment: How does changing STATE_FINISH not mess with the library? What about the one definition rule?

Comment: Even if you somehow manage to change the value of `STATE_FINISH`,the "insides" of your library won't ever see the change and still treat `3` as `STATE_FINISH` -- so: don't do it.

Comment: Succinctly, there isn't a way to change an `enum` once its declaration is complete.  As you mention, you could use a `#define` to achieve the effect, but that's a pretty horrid botch job (so it is a good thing that you can't use it).  The real question is: _Why on earth would you want to do it?_

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the `#undef` will not have an effect. That only works on names that have been `#define`d. So you should leave that out.

Second, the `#define STATE_FINISH 2` would likely have the effect that you seem to want. You must however be sure that it is always used in all cases where the header is `#include`d. Otherwise, the value that is used in your program for STATE_FINISH will be inconsistent. Also you must do the `#define` *after* the `#include`. If you do it before, it will already do the substitution in the header file, which will change the `enum` definition into the incorrect

```
typedef enum {
   STATE_INITIAL  = 0,
   STATE_LOAD     = 1,
   STATE_READ     = 2,
   2   = 3 /* or STATE_READ = 3, for the other variant; also wrong */
} state_t;
```

Now combining these warnings about order: you can't get that guaranteed right. If you re-`#define` after the `#include`, maybe some code inside the header files has already used `STATE_FINISH`, which will not have been replaced. Depending on what you want, this may be wrong.

Next, are you really sure you want to do this? Why? And don't you perhaps mean `#define STATE_FINISH STATE_READ` instead? The difference seems subtle, but is about expressing what you really mean.

Maybe what you mean is more like `#define MY_OWN_STATE STATE_READ`? If you use your own invented name for the state, you will cause less confusion about the true meaning of `STATE_FINISH`. It also expresses the fact that you can't change the value of `STATE_FINISH` as used within the library (which I hope you already realised, of course).

Comment: The `#undef` is not necessarily without effect; maybe some other header also thought that `STATE_FINISH` should have a different value, perhaps `1`, and then the `#undef` cancels that remapping.  But you're right that the `#undef` doesn't alter the `enum` in any way.

Comment: You're right. I was trying not to complicate things. But the more I think about this, the more complications I can think of (which get reflected in a growing ever more cautious answer) :-)

Comment: @Rhialto, before posting I already tried #define STATE_FINISH 2 or better #define STATE_FINISH STATE_READ, however the compiler is not happy about this ("the symbol is declared in another unit").

Comment: That's the way it goes.  The more you spend time thinking about the situation, the more you realize that there are devious tweaks that an aberrent, if not abhorrent, programmer could be doing to make life hell (for themselves and you).  It's not uncommon.  Beware of over-polishing (and on that score, do as I say, not as I do).

Comment: I like the caveat that the original enum value may have been used in the header already and that there is no way to prevent that (short of changing the header which would be best anyway, except it would be wrong without changing the library, as would be the #define). That makes a re-`#define` even more dangerous. I also like the re-definition by means of the enum which is more robust against lib updates.

Comment: @Mark: Usually an error message like that is used for variables that get multiple definitions. Of course that depends on which compiler you're using, since they have quite a lot of leeway in the sort of diagnostics they may issue. But apart from that, maybe it is the case that some other header file in your project also already tries the same trick with #define STATE_FINISH? Trying multiple #defines for the same name that don't have the same value is supposed to get a diagnostic. If the message goes away if you do the #undef first, this seems to be likely the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you dare you can just say

```
#define STATE_FINISH 2
```

No need to #undefine anything since typedefs are not preprocessor commands. Your preprocessor define will now replace all occurrences of STATE_FINISH with 2 so that the actual compiler never sees that identifier.

Whether that makes sense though is another question.

Update: I can't nail it down, but subtle problems may arise when the enum is represented by a different integer type (say, a char). C doesn't have overloadeded functions though which would be the most glaring problem in C++ (and that independent of the underlying type).

Comment: The question does say that the `#define` can't be used (without giving any justification for that).

Comment: wouldn't this just replace `STATE_FINISH` with `2` in the enum declaration, causing the compiler to attempt to compile a line that says `2 = 3`?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow: The context is presumed to be `#include "library.h"` followed by `#define STATE_FINISH 2`.  Otherwise, yes, you would run into problems as you suggest.  And if there's more than one file that needs this remapping, you're looking at creating a new header `library-wrapper.h` which has its include guards, includes `library.h` and then does the remapping.  The `library-wrapper.h` header would be used whenever the services of the library are needed — as a local coding standard.

Comment: oh, derp. i completely misunderstood the question. good answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The OP says he cannot #undef and then #define. My assumption is that the problem is in the attempt to #undef something that was never #defined (as opposed to typedef'ed).

Comment: @PeterSchneider: writing `#undef NEVER_EVER_BEEN_USED_BEFORE_IN_THE_HISTORY_OF_STACK_OVERFLOW` can't cause an error in a C compiler released during the course of the current millennium, and shouldn't have caused errors in most of those released in the previous millennium.  (OK: "can't" is an exaggeration, but said compiler would provide enough concerns that this is probably not the major problem.  The C standard has always required `#undef undefined_name` to be a quiet no-op.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was not aware of that and have seen so many `#ifdef-#undef-#define` sequences that this pattern seems almost iconic to me. Then indeed the OP possibly "can not" re-`#define` for some other reason. I let the answer stand anyway ...